# Jsp Include File Directive with Variable FileName in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, include

I  have passed filename using ModelAndView object in my spring mvc application. But am unable to fix this compilation issue. Im new to WEB-Development.

Following is content of my jsp page.

```
<% String pageRed = "static/" + (String)request.getAttribute("redPage"); %>
<%@ include file="<%=pageRed %>" %>
```

Include File Line gives the following error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Start tag (<jsp:directive.include>) not closed properly, expected '>'.
    - A file value is required in this directive
    - Invalid location of text ("<%=pageRed %>" %) in tag 
     (<jsp:directive.include>).
```

Any idea  ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use <%@ include file="<%=pageRed %>" %>

Can use  instead of

```
<jsp:include page="static/${redPage_name}.jsp" />
```

it was work for me

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, as include directives are resolved during the **servlet translation time**, whereas `(String)request.getAttribute("redPage");` gets resolved at runtime.

What is the reason behind doing it this way?